# Store results of a calculation automatically under a new macro name

Tags: macros, siunitx, expl3, l3fp

As I am now accessing values from tables via a macro to make dynamic references in the text (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84673/accessing-values-from-tables-via-grid-search)) and make calculations with it, I need a way to make the resulting variables under which the values are stored more user friendly. Because of LaTeX' limitation of not allowing numbers or any separator in a macro name (and I have many macros), I use the "`\csname\dots\endcsname`" approach from the TeX FAQ to create more meaningful names.

This results in the following complication, illustrated in the MWE below: I use `siunitx` to print numbers via `\num` or `\SI`. As these commands accept only numbers, I can't make calculations within those. I use `l3fp` to make the calculations and store the the result under a (temporary) name. This results in two lines of code for every single variable:

```
\calc{\Numtest}{500/2}% store result
\DefineRemark{num:test}{\Numtest}% label result
```

And within the text the result would be called as `\num{\Remark{num:test}}`. I want to combine the two commands into one that would be something like `\newcalc{<varname>}{<calculation>}`. The following does not work because `\temp` does not get overwritten. I would require a new random name for every single instance of `\newcalc`.

```
\newcommand{\newcalc}[2]{%
\calc{\temp}{#2}
\DefineRemark{#1}{\temp}
}
```

What is a way to solve this issue? On another note in the MWE I created two new commands based on `\num` and `\SI` that incorporates the `\Remark` macro. Is it a good idea to create these commands by copying the original definition completely?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{siunitx,xparse,expl3}

% simple calculation command that stores the result
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\calc} { m m } {
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \fp_to_tl:n {#2} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Workaround for non-letters in macro names
\newcommand{\DefineRemark}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname rmk-#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\Remark}[1]{\csname rmk-#1\endcsname}

% Create \Num and \NUM based on siunitx' \num and \SI to incorporate the above directly
% (so \Num is \num{\remark{.}}). Not sure if it as a good idea to do it that way
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \Num { o m } {
  \leavevmode
  \group_begin:
    \IfNoValueF {#1}
      { \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1} }
    \__siunitx_number_output:n {\Remark{#2}}
  \group_end:
}
\NewDocumentCommand \NUM { o m o m } {
  \leavevmode
  \group_begin:
    \IfNoValueTF {#1}
      { \__siunitx_combined:nnnn { } {\Remark{#2}} {#3} {#4} }
      {
        \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1}
        \__siunitx_combined:nnnn {#1} {\Remark{#2}} {#3} {#4}
      }
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Test if \Num and \NUM Works
\calc{\Numtest}{500/2}
\DefineRemark{num:test}{\Numtest}

% Trying to combine \calc and \DefineRemark
% This does not work :( Would need to create a new "\temp" each time
\newcommand{\newcalc}[2]{%
\calc{\temp}{#2}
\DefineRemark{#1}{\temp}
}

\newcalc{new:calc1}{250/2}
\newcalc{new:calc2}{125/2}


\begin{document}

Test Num and NUM Macros: \Num{num:test} and \NUM{num:test}{\percent}

\vspace{2ex}

Test the combination of calc and DefineRemark. The two values should be
different: \Num{new:calc1} and \Num{new:calc2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It sounds like `fp.sty` would do what you want.. `\FPdiv\myresult{250}{2}` will store 125 in \myresult.  \FPclip is also necessary to remove leading and trailing zeros.  But this approach integrates well with `siunitx`

Comment: As `l3fp` is expandable, why not just do the calculation within the argument of `\num`?

Comment: @BrandonKuczenski The problem would be the same, since his `\calc{\myresult}{250 / 2}` is equivalent to `\FPdiv\myresult{250}{2}` (up to how leading/trailing zeros are treated, perhaps).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest quite a different approach:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{siunitx,xparse,expl3}

% simple calculation command that stores the result
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\calc}{ m m }
 {
  \tl_set:cx { l_jorg_rmk_#1_tl } { \fp_to_tl:n { #2 } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\usekey}{ m }
 {
  \tl_use:c { l_jorg_rmk_#1_tl }
 }
% Create \Num and \NUM based on siunitx' \num and \SI to incorporate the above directly
% (so \Num is \num{\remark{.}}). Not sure if it as a good idea to do it that way
\NewDocumentCommand \Num { o m }
 {
  \leavevmode
  \group_begin:
    \IfNoValueF {#1}
      { \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1} }
    \__siunitx_number_output:n {\tl_use:c { l_jorg_rmk_#2_tl } }
  \group_end:
}
\NewDocumentCommand \NUM { o m o m }
 {
  \leavevmode
  \group_begin:
    \IfNoValueTF {#1}
      { \__siunitx_combined:nnnn { } { \tl_use:c { l_jorg_rmk_#2_tl } } {#3} {#4} }
      {
        \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1}
        \__siunitx_combined:nnnn {#1} { \tl_use:c { l_jorg_rmk_#2_tl } } {#3} {#4}
      }
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Test if \Num and \NUM Works
\calc{num:test}{500/2}
\calc{new:calc1}{250/2}
\calc{new:calc2}{125/2}


\begin{document}

Test Num and NUM Macros: \Num{num:test} and \NUM{num:test}{\percent}

\vspace{2ex}

Test the combination of calc and DefineRemark. The two values should be
different: \Num{new:calc1} and \Num{new:calc2}

\vspace{2ex}

Here's a key used by itself: \usekey{num:test}

\end{document}
```

However, using `\__siunitx_number_output:n` and `\__siunitx_combined:nnnn` is an improper way to proceed, because these are commands prefixed by `__` which makes them "internals", so bound to be changed without notice (thanks Bruno Le Floch for remarking it).

In my opinion `siunitx` *should* make available public interfaces to the internal commands, but at the moment there are many risks in using the commands in this way. So a better suggestion is to change the definitions of `\Num` and `\NUM` as follows

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Num} { o m }
 {
   \num [ #1 ] { \tl_use:c { l_jorg_rmk_#2_tl } }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\NUM} { o m o m }
 {
  \SI [ #1 ] { \tl_use:c { l_jorg_rmk_#2_tl } } [ #3 ] { #4 }
 }
```

which is even simpler. The calls of `\SI` and `\num` should take into account by themselves the `\IfNoValue...` business.

Comment: That's brilliant so much simpler than what I was trying to do. It's alsway great that I can just use the integer via `usekey`. Thanks!

Comment: @egreg: if you change the definitions of `\Num` and `\NUM` to what I give in my answer (without using the internals of siunitx, likely to change), I can delete my answer so that there is one definite answer.  Perhaps it is worth to explicitly point out that internals should not be used.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch You're right and Joseph is wrong in not providing a "non internal" macro, but defining `\SI` and `\num` in terms of internals only. We were discussing exactly this in chat a couple of days ago.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch The reason why I copied the commands from siunitx was because I wanted to alter my custom command to `\Num[SI-options]<pre-unit>{number}[measure]` where all but `number` are optional. I have done this by creating a `\cs_new_protected:Npn` that changes the order of the original `SI` command and then define the `\Num` command accordingly. I don't know if this can be done in an easier way without relying on `siunitx` internals.

Comment: @Jörg I encourage you to write a question about that: your comment is not detailed enough for me to understand exactly what you want to acheive.  It should be possible perhaps to do `\NewDocumentCommand{\Num}{omo}{\IfNoValue{#3}{\num[#1]{#2}}{\SI[#1]{#2}{#3}}}`?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I'll do that :-)