# Why does \@gobble take one argument

Tags: macros, tex-core

I understand what `\@gobble`, `\@gobbletwo` etc. do, but I don't understand why `\@gobble` allows for an argument.

I believe that the definition of the macro is `\long\def\@gobble#1{}`. Why is this argument needed?

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84702/11984) answer for instance David Carlisle defines `\global\advance\rowc\@ne\@gobble{##}&&%`. Does it mean that only `##` are gobbled?

Comment: The purpose of `\@gobble` is precisely to gobble one argument.

Comment: Davids answer is within table constructions, they are a very special beast. In general, see egregs answer

Comment: the meaning of `##` is strange, not the command `\@gobble`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The definition of `\@gobble` is equivalent to

```
\newcommand{\@gobble}[1]{}
```

so, when used, it will simply throw away its argument. When you say something like

```
\let\macro\@gobble
```

you're telling TeX that `\macro` *will* throw away its argument. Instead

```
\@gobble{something}
```

throws away `{something}` as soon as TeX finds it.

---

Let's see the code you're referring to:

```
\long\def\savedata#1{%
  \setbox0\vbox\bgroup
  \let\\\cr
  \let\midrule\@empty
  \let\multicolumn\@gobbletwo
  \everyeof{\noexpand}%
  \halign\bgroup
  \global\colc\z@
  \global\advance\rowc\@ne\@gobble{##}&&%
  \global\advance\colc\@ne
  \expandafter\xdef\csname data-#1(\the\rowc,\the\colc)\endcsname
  {\zap@space## \@empty}\cr
  \@@input #1 
  \crcr\egroup\egroup}
```

Its purpose is to load a file (the argument to `\savedata`) which contains what usually would go between `\begin{tabular}{l...}` and `\end{tabular}`, in order to gather data from it.

The table is typeset inside a box, which will not be used afterwards (`\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup`) and in this box, which forms a group, some macros are redefined: `\let\\\cr` and `\let\midrule\@empty`. The first is to make `\\` into the simple table line terminator, the second is because `\midrule` is meaningless for the purpose. Also `\multicolumn` is redefined:

```
\let\multicolumn\@gobbletwo
```

so that, when TeX will see `\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}` it will leave only `{(1)}` in the input stream, because `\@gobbletwo` looks for two arguments and doesn't do anything with them, so they simply disappear. Probably

```
\let\multicolumn\@thirdofthree
```

would be theoretically better, but in the end the result is just the same. Can you see now why? Your input file will possibly contain `\multicolumn`, but in this context we are only interested in the third argument, because we are not really typesetting a table, but only storing its contents (cell by cell) in macros.

A technically important `\everyeof{\noexpand}` is issued (I won't discuss it) and then a `\halign` is opened.

The syntax for the primitive `\halign` is quite interesting; I'm not going into the details, but basically it is

```
\halign{<template>\cr
  <table row>\cr
  ...
  <table row>\cr
}
```

where `<template>` is a collection of specifications for each table column in the form `<before>#<after>` and separated by `&`. The `#` represents the cell contents. A `&&` sequence means that the following specifications are repeated as many times as the table needs.

In this case the template is

```
  \global\colc\z@
  \global\advance\rowc\@ne\@gobble{##}&&%
  \global\advance\colc\@ne
  \expandafter\xdef\csname data-#1(\the\rowc,\the\colc)\endcsname
  {\zap@space## \@empty}\cr
```

which specifies a first column where the counter representing the columns is set to 0 and the one representing rows is advanced by one. Then the cell contents is passed to `\@gobble`, so it will vanish, as we don't need it.

The rest of the table is a sequence of columns with the following specification: the column counter is stepped and macros of the form

```
\data-<argument>(i,j)
```

(`<argument>` is the argument to `\savedata`, in parentheses are the row and column indices, as numbers; the macro name can't be written with ordinary means, but `\csname...\endcsname` allows for those strange characters in the name). The replacement text for this macro provides eventually the cell contents with leading and trailing spaces removed (`\zap@space## \@empty`). The `\cr` ends the template.

<sub>As Ahmed Musa remarks, the `\zap@space` macro should be used with care, because it zaps *all spaces*; in this case it's unimportant, because the significant entries don't contain spaces.</sub>

Finally the table contents is input so that the macros will be defined; `\\` will be translated into the primitive `\cr` to provide line terminations (the more complex job that `\\` does in LaTeX `tabular` environments is not needed here) and `\multicol{1}{c}{(1)}` will leave only `{(1)}`.

The table is terminated by `\crcr` which will not add a line if the code ends with `\\`. The first `\egroup` matches the `\bgroup` after `\halign` and the second one the `\bgroup` after `\vbox`.

Note that here the "cell contents placeholder", ordinarily `#`, has to be doubled because we are inside a definition.

Comment: "The replacement text for this macro is the cell contents with leading and trailing spaces removed." `\zap@space` is invasive. Try `\edef\x{\zap@space a b c d \@empty}`. And use `\zap@space`, not `\zap@spaces`.

Comment: @AhmedMusa I was commenting David's code; you find the link to the original answer.

Comment: @AhmedMusa The code uses `zap@space` there is just a little typo in the answer above.

Comment: @egreg I wish I could upvote this answer several times. It's really helpful, thanks a lot!

Comment: @egreg: I meant to say that `\zap@space` doesn’t remove **leading and trailing spaces**; it really zaps all spaces in the token list. Unless it was redefined in `\tabular`.

Comment: @AhmedMusa In the application the code is meant for, `#1` has only leading and trailing spaces; the rest are digits that for a number.

Comment: I always wondered what that code was doing, good to see some documentation for it.