# Delaying command expansion that appears in \begin handler until \end handler executes

Tags: macros, environments, expansion, etoolbox

I have a custom environment for handling a code interface declaration that is specified as:

```
\begin{decl}{FOO}
\param{in}{bar} the bar input parameter
\param{out}{baz} the baz input parameter
\end{decl}
```

This is being typeset as a nested list by my package (note: reality is much more complicated, but this captures the idea, mostly).

```
\newrobustcmd*{\param}[2]{
  \item[#1 #2]
}

\newenvironment{decl}[1]{
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item #1(<param names here>)
    \begin{description}
}{
    \end{description}
  \end{enumerate}
}
```

My problem is that I need to accumulate the `\param` names, and then in the `\end{decl}` handler I need to inject them in the location tagged as `<param names here>`. Unfortunately, I don't know the list I want to inject at the time that I'm generating that item.

Is there a canonical way to do this?

I was considering using the `etoolbox` list functionality to build internal lists as I process `\param`s, and then generating the whole `enumerate` structure in the `\end{decl}` handler, but I don't know how to capture the "description" `\parbox` for the `\param` for use later without using `\par`, which as far as I know requires a paragraph break between `\param` items, which doesn't exist in the source. I could introduce a third parameter to `\param` such that the description can be dealt with as a third parameter, but this involves quite a large change to the .tex source base.

I'd really prefer a way to `\appto` a command used in place of `<param names here>`, but this doesn't seem to work because use of the `\appto`ed command is eagerly expanded in the `\begin{decl}` handler and the appended strings aren't getting used.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`? Include also an example how you use your environment/command and how it should look like. And: The syntax for `\newenvironment` is backslash-less: `\newenvironment{decl}…`

Comment: Sorry about the newenvironment bug. I'll wrap it in a document the next time I have a question. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is there a canonical way? Well, this is one way.

The `environ` package allows us to use the collected `\BODY` of the environment to use more than once.

We use it twice:

1. To build the `\@paramlist` that contains the two arguments of `\param`. This is “executed” inside a box that is not type set.
2. With the original definition of `\param` the `\BODY` is actually typeset in the `description` environment.

#### Notes

- The initial definition of `\@paramlist` is `\@gobbletwo` which has the only purpose to gobble the first comma and space. Depending on your output of this list, you might change the whole process and the definition of `decl@param`.
- When the `\@paramlist` is used, it is directly followed by two `\@empty` (defined as `\def\@empty{}`. In the case of no occurrence of a `\param` in the environment this will stop `\@paramlist` (i.e. `\@gobbletwo`) to grab `)` and more importantly `\begin`.
  (Thanks to [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) who has used this in [his (deleted) answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105730/16595).)

  #### Reference
- [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/16595)
- [Why does \@gobble take one argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85796/16595)
- [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/16595) (if `\param` contains optional arguments or is defined via `xparse`)
- [\setbox vs. \sbox and \savebox - What are the differences I need to know about?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46480/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,environ}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*\orig@param[2]{\item[{#1 #2}]}%
\newrobustcmd*\decl@param[2]{\gappto\@paramlist{,\ #1 #2}}% needs to be global
\NewEnviron{decl}[1]{%
  \def\@paramlist{\@gobbletwo}% \@gobbletwo will remove the first comma and space
  \let\param\decl@param
  \sbox0{\BODY}% will not be typeset but "executed"
  \let\param\orig@param
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item #1 (\@paramlist\@empty\@empty)
    \begin{description}
        \BODY
    \end{description}
  \end{enumerate}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{decl}{Environment contains}
\param{Foo}{Bar} Foobar
\param{Ding}{Dong} Dingenskirchen
\param{La}{TeX} LaTeX
\end{decl}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: That's great, I haven't run into that \sbox usage before. This should work out perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\newenvironment` without loading helper packages provided you're willing to run your document twice. Anyway, you must run it twice to get references (section, etc.) right. Thanks to `egreg` for his comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcount\paramenvcount
\newcommand*\addparam[2]{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\tempa\csname paramlist/#1\endcsname
  \ifdefined\tempa
    \ifx\tempa\relax\def\tempa{}\fi
  \else
    \def\tempa{}%
  \fi
  \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname paramlist/#1\endcsname{%
    \tempa\ifx\tempa\empty\else, \fi#2%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\param}[1]{\@testopt{\param@a{#1}}\space}
\def\param@a#1[#2]#3{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \noexpand\addparam{\the\paramenvcount}{\unexpanded{#1#2#3}}%
  }%
  \item[#1#2#3]%
}
\newenvironment{decl}[1]{%
  \global\advance\paramenvcount\@ne
  \begin{enumerate}%
  \item #1 (\@nameuse{paramlist/\the\paramenvcount})
  \begin{description}%
}{%
  \end{description}%
  \end{enumerate}%
}
\makeatother

% Tests:
\begin{document}
\begin{decl}{Environment 1 contains}
\param{Foo}{Bar} Foobar
\param{Ding}{Dong} Dingenskirchen
\param{La}[]{TeX} \LaTeX
\end{decl}

\begin{decl}{Environment 2 contains}
\param{Foo2}[*]{Bar2} Foobar2
\param{Ding2}[*]{Dong2} Dingenskirchen2
\param{La}[]{TeX2} \LaTeX2
\end{decl}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In your approach, there is always only one `\item` of `\enumerate` within `\decl`. I find the outcome rather uninteresting. I would have used the following scheme.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcount\entryenvcount
\newcommand*\gettempa[1]{%
  \begingroup\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter
  \let\expandafter\tempa\csname paramlist/#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand*\addparam[2]{%
  \gettempa{#1}%
  \ifdefined\tempa\else\def\tempa{}\fi
  \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname paramlist/#1\endcsname{%
    \tempa\ifx\tempa\empty\else, \fi#2%
  }%
}
\newenvironment{decl}[1]{%
  \global\advance\entryenvcount\@ne
  \def\entry{\@testopt\entry@a{}}%
  \def\entry@a[##1]{%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
      \noexpand\addparam{\the\entryenvcount}{\unexpanded{##1}}%
    }%
    \labelwidth=-\if\relax\detokenize{##1}\relax3.25\else5\fi mm\relax
    \item[##1]%
  }%
  \gettempa{\the\entryenvcount}%
  \protected@xdef\tempa{%
    \ifdefined\tempa\ifx\tempa\empty\else(\tempa)\fi\fi
  }%
  \noindent\hbox to 5mm{\the\entryenvcount.\hfil}#1~\tempa
  \begin{description}%
}{%
  \end{description}%
}
\makeatother

% Tests:
\begin{document}
\begin{decl}{Environment 1 contains}
\entry[Foo, Bar] Foobar
\entry[Ding, Dong] Dingdong
\entry[La,TeX] \LaTeX
\end{decl}

\begin{decl}{Environment 2 contains}
\entry[Foo2, Bar2] Foobar2
\entry[Ding2, Dong2] Dingdong2
\entry[La,TeX2] \LaTeX2
\end{decl}

\begin{decl}{Environment 3 contains no tags}
\entry Foobar3
\entry Dingdong3
\entry \LaTeX3
\end{decl}
\end{document}
```

[image]