# Remove Title of the paper from Table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, author-number

I am writing a report using lncs package. In my table of contents, the title of the page and author's name is also appearing. How do i remove this?

```
\title{Evaluation of xyz}
\author{Alina}
\institute{University}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
```

Above is the code I have written and in the picture you could see the  result. I want to remove the title & author from table of contents and start it from introduction.
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: When publishing with Springer, changing the layout is not your decision. If not publishing with Springer, why use their style at all? It will just give you troubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Evaluation of xyz}
\author{Alina}
\institute{University}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{}
\maketitle
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{\oldaddcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note: The title is added to table of contents via `\addcontentsline{}{}{}` command in the definition of `\maketitle` of `llncs` class file. Hence, if you need to remove it, I have stored the definition of `\addcontentsline` to a temporary control sequence `\oldaddcontentsline` using `\let`. After `\maketitle`, the original definition is restored.

**Edit:** An easy alternative solution is to redefine `\addcontentsline` within a group for `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Evaluation of xyz}
\author{Alina}
\institute{University}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
{\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{}\maketitle}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to store and restore the command. Just put it within `{}` and it will keep it local. like this: `{\let\addcontentsline\relax
\maketitle}`

Comment: @RunarTrollet Yea. I missed that :-) Will that  work if it is relaxed? You need to `\@gobble` it.

Comment: @JagathAR No, `\relax` will work just fine. `\@gobble` I think would be dangerous here, as it only throws away one argument. I am not quite sure, though. see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85796/why-does-gobble-take-one-argument

Comment: @RunarTrollet It should not be `{\let\addcontentsline\relax \maketitle}` instead  `{\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{}\maketitle}`. Sorry `\@gobble` will also cause problem.

Comment: @Jagath: The scoped solution given here in your final comment is much neater than the one you present in your answer. Would you consider updating the answer accordingly?

Comment: @figlesquidge: Updated the answer.